# Intermediate fields of $X^p - 2 $

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

I've been working on an exercise I have to do for my algebra course.

**Exercise:**
Let p be prime and $L$ the splitting field of $ f = X^p - 2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

**a)** Show that $ Gal(L/\mathbb{Q})$ is isomorphic to the subgroup
$$ H = \left \{
\begin{pmatrix}
a && b  \\
0 && 1
\end{pmatrix} \; \rvert \; a \in \mathbb{F}_p^* , b \in \mathbb{F}_p \right \} \subseteq GL_2(\mathbb{F}_p) $$

**b)** Determine all intermediate fields $E$ of $L/\mathbb{Q}$ such that $ [ E : \mathbb{Q} ] = p - 1$.

I was able to do a) using that f is irreducible and we can get the degree of the extension by looking at:
$$ \mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p] 2 , \xi) = L $$

Where $\xi$ is the p-th root of unity. We can now see that $[L : \mathbb{Q} ] = p(p-1) $ since $\xi \notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p] 2) $.

Therefore $ |Gal(L / \mathbb{Q})| = p(p-1) = |H| $.

I was now able to show that these groups are isomorphic. I did it by using that all automorphisms $\tau$ are given by 
$$ \xi \mapsto \xi^k \; , \; k \in [p-1] \\
\sqrt[p] 2 \mapsto \xi^j \cdot \sqrt[p] 2 \; , \; j \in [p] $$

and we can easily declare an isomorphism through $ j $ and $ k$.

With b) I got stuck. I am not able to match subgroups for these intermediate fields $E$.

How can I do that?

Comment: If by $S_n$ you mean the symmetric group on the $n$-element set, how is $S_{p-2}$ normal in $S_p$?

Comment: Yes, I mean the symmetric group - but that was just a guess I quickly made.

Comment: @kummerer94 You may want to check groups of order $\;\frac{|G|}{p-1}=p\;$ and use some Sylow stuff.

Comment: We have not done so much Sylow stuff so far, but thank you very much for this hint! Could you elaborate a bit more what you had in mind with Sylow stuff so I can check whether we have already worked with it or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Size}[1]{\lvert #1 \rvert}$$\newcommand{\Gal}{\mathrm{Gal}}$$\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}$Let $L'= H$ be the subgroup of $G = \Gal(L/\Q)$ corresponding to $L$. Then
$$
\Size{H} = \Size{H : \{ 1 \}} = \Size{ \{1\}' : H'} = \Size{L : E} = \frac{\Size{L : \Q}}{\Size{E : \Q}} = \frac{p(p-1)}{p-1} = p.
$$
Now show that $G$ has a unique subgroup of order $p$.

Here I am writing $X'$ for the subgroup of $G$ corresponding to the intermediate field $X$, and also for the intermediate field corresponding to the subgroup $X$.

To show that there is a unique subgroup of order $p$, just note that if $a \ne 1$, then
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a && b  \\
0 && 1
\end{bmatrix}^{p}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
a^{p} && (a^{p-1} + a^{p-2} + \dots + a + 1) b  \\
0 && 1
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
a && b  \\
0 && 1
\end{bmatrix},
$$
so a matrix of order $p$ must have $a = 1$. (While for $a \ne 1$ the matrix has order dividing $p-1$.)

Here I have used that if $a \ne 1$, then
$$
a^{p-1} + a^{p-2} + \dots + a + 1
=
\frac{a^{p} - 1}{a - 1} = \frac{a -1}{a-1} = 1.
$$

Comment: What is $\{1\}'$?

Comment: Just added an explanation of the notation.

Comment: Nice answer! Thank you very much. So I can conclude there is only one intermediate field $E$ so that $[E:\mathbb{Q}] = p-1$ since there is only one subgroup?

The subgroup would be $H$ with fixed $a = 1$ and $b\in \mathbb{F}_p$?

Comment: Yes. And then of course the intermediate field is $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$.

Comment: Ah! That's neat. - Thank you so much, if not for you I think I would have tried the whole thing (stubbornly, not looking at a) enough) with permutations of roots!